# Do similar/identical magnet rings stack?

Tags: stardew-valley

I just got a Small Magnet Ring but I'm already wearing one. Do the two rings stack, increasing my collection further?

Comment: I know that two glow rings stack (increasing the radius of the light centered around your character). I'm not sure if that also applies to other rings.

Comment: This is the best news I've seen all day

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ConcernedApe confirmed that magnet rings do stack.

Source: https://twitter.com/ConcernedApe/status/704185979855220736